# Defining abstract base model that can be referenced in another model in Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance

Having these models in Django. Album and Playlist as song collections. Library consists of playlists and albums. After I defined base model to hold some common fields of Album and Playlist, some complications occured:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    release_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Album(Collection):
    pass

class Playlist(Collection):
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_liked_songs_playlist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Library(models.Model):
    collections = models.ManyToManyField("Collection", related_name="libraries")
    # playlists = models.ManyToManyField("Playlist", related_name="libraries")
    # albums = models.ManyToManyField("Album", related_name="libraries", blank=True)
```

This code errors since Collection is abstract. Is is possible to change somehow that so that works without changing Collection from abstract to regular? I do not want Collection model has its own table in db. Maybe I need to change type of relation from ManyToManyField to some other? Please advice

UPD.
Solution to this problem using only official Django resources, no third-party packages:

```
class Library(models.Model):
    pass


class LibraryCollection(models.Model):
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="collections")
    collection_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    collection = GenericForeignKey("collection_content_type", "collection_object_id")
```

Comment: No, in fact even if you make `Collection` concrete (non-abstract), if a `Library `contain an `Album` and a `Playlist` for example, it will only return `Collection` *objects*, not `Album`s or `Playlist`s, so it does not even "downcast" so to speak.

Comment: What workaround would you suggest please? better getting rid of ```Collections``` and simply have two fields i ```Library``` for both ```playlists``` and ```albums```?

Comment: I think you can use generic relations. check out this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations